# Keep selection in QGraphicsScene?

Tags: qgraphicsscene, multipleselection

In QGraphicsScene, with Ctrl modifier I can select multiple items. But, if I click on blank field on QGraphicsScene (even though I press "**Ctrl**" Key), it lose it's own previous selection. I want to keep it's selection when I press on "**Ctrl**" Key, but I don't know how to achieve that. I think that I can change **QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent**, but it is impossible.
Any helps can be useful.

Comment: is my question is so dumb? :)